# Sync Wall post between Fanpage and Comments plugin

Tags: plugins, facebook-comments

I've been trying to find a way to sync comments posted on facebook with comments that are posted on a website. I have tried using the comments plugin but have noticed that posts from the fanpage, are not pushed to the comments plugin. Is there a way to sync up the wall posts?